# How to get text input and paste it in front of a link using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm currently busy with (re)making the dutch Wikipedia site. And I want to make the search bar. My idea was to get text input and when you click on search the text will go to the front of a link like this:

https://ibb.co/XbndsKP

This is currently the search bar:

```
<div align='center'>
    <form method="submit" action='php/zoeken.php'>

        <input placeholder="zoeken"id="zoeken"class='zoeken'type="text">
        <button class='button'type="submit">zoeken</button>
</div>
```

Comment: And your question or problem is? Btw, your FORM isn't closed properly, I think you won't get any post requests with that...

Comment: Where is the code that handles the submitted data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="THE PAGE YOU SENT REQUEST" method="POST">
  <input placeholder="zoeken" name="zoaken" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 

  /* Get the text input with $_POST */
  $string = $_POST['zoaken'];

  /* Redirect the page to the new address */
  header('Location: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/'.$string);
```

You should also check if the text is null, empty or has vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

The better way it's use JS. Get value of input and redirect like this

```
document.location = 'http://nl.wikipedia.com/search_word';
```

Comment: Why "must" the OP use JS? It might be a good alternative, but "must" is a bit too absolute.

Comment: Because it's more easier way, then PHP with many verifications

Comment: You're missing my point. The OP doesn't _have to_ use JS for this. Like I said, it might be a good option, but saying that the OP "must" use it isn't accurate. "must" means that it can't be done without JS, which it can.